# cell not showing if using UITableView static content

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've been trying to using custom tableview cell in static tableview. But my cell is not showing up.

I tried not to using custom tableview cell, using basic is showing, only the custom one.

Something like this one.
[image: In the storyboard]
 [image: Here for better picture]

NB :

- I'm using UITableViewController
- In the Debug -> View Hierarchy, the content view is empty.
- I don't have any code related to the TableView delegate or datasource
- I'm using xcode 7 beta 6

Comment: "I don't have any code related to the TableView delegate or datasource"
you need to implement these.

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain, for static content no, he don't.

Comment: Cy-4AH hm okk. I thought he had to.